# how to find the running process and kill the process in QT?

Tags: qt, process, symbian, nokia, kill

i am developing a very simple application for nokia mobile.my task is to find what are all the process currently running ? after that i have to kill(exit that application i.e camera or musicplayer) that process! i have tried to find some simple method in Qprocess but there is no function to listout the current process. is there any possible way in NokiaQT or i have to use symbianC++????

Answer (score 2):

Qt does not provide an API to do this.  You will need to use the appropriate OS API instead.  I'm not familiar with Symbian, so I can't tell you what that might be.

Comment: whether symbian having any os releated api? any symbian experts?