# How to kill process by process name in Qt

Tags: windows, qt, process

I'm writing desktop application for windows in Qt.
I have name of 3 processes that if they are running I want to kill them in the begining of my application.
What the best way to do it?(get the status of process by using the process name, and kill it if it's open).

code example can help me a lot.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538967/how-to-find-the-running-process-and-kill-the-process-in-qt?rq=1

Answer (score 12):

You can use Qprocess for this purpose.
At the start of your application,Do

```
Qprocess p;
p.start("pkill processname1");
p.waitForFinished();
p.start("pkill processname2");
p.waitForFinished();
p.start("pkill processname2");
p.waitForFinished();
```

Or you can use system call directly..

```
system("pkill processname1");
system("pkill processname2");
system("pkill processname3");
```

In Windows environment, you can use following commands to kill process

```
process -k “Process ID”
process -k “Process Name”
```

You can read more of these [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/446/xp_kill_windows_process_command_line_taskkill/).

Comment: thanks, The command pkill is work also in windows? is it more good than native win32 api

Comment: Is it better that using WIN32 API? if so, why?

Comment: `'pkill' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: `'process' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck On Windows use `taskkill /im program.exe` or `taskkill /pid 123`

Answer (score 6):

Under Windows use taskkill command
You can call it using

```
QProcess::execute("taskkill /im <processname> /f");
```

Or

```
system("taskkill /im <processname> /f");
```

Answer (score 1):

QT does not provide any API for killing processes that is not created by your QT project. If you are on Windows you can try following code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956519/how-to-kill-processes-by-name-win32-api)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <string.h>
void killProcessByName(const char *filename)
{
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    while (hRes)
    {
        if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                                          (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID);
            if (hProcess != NULL)
            {
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
        hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}
int main()
{
    killProcessByName("notepad++.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to Run App

```
bool ok = QProcess::startDetached("C:\\TTEC\\CozxyLogger\\CozxyLogger.exe");
qDebug() <<  "Run = " << ok;
```

How to Kill App

```
 system("taskkill /im CozxyLogger.exe /f");
 qDebug() << "Close";[enter image description here][1]
```

More at link ::

http://sittikron-big-rmutt.blogspot.com/2018/01/qt-start-and-kill.html

Answer (score -4):

In Windows right click the taskbar, select Task Manager, on the Process tab, find the process by Name..End task.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.